# Flutter GraphQL subscription connection problem

Tags: flutter, graphql

I am trying to use GraphQL subscription in flutter. I am using only graphql: ^5.1.3.
Here is my client code:

```
@Singleton()
class GraphQlClient {
  GraphQLClient? client;

  void init() {
    _initConnection();
  }

  void _initConnection() async {
    final graphQlHost = UrlTool.graphQlUrl();
    final subscriptionQlHost = UrlTool.subscriptionUrl();
  
    final token = getIt<LoginCubit>().state.userToken;
    
    logger.i('init basic connection');
    logger.i(token);
    
    final httpLink = HttpLink(graphQlHost);

    final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
      getToken: () async {
        final sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final token = sharedPref.getString(kMerchantToken);
        return token == null ? null : 'Bearer $token';
      },
    ); // Fetch token securely
    final link = Link.split(
      (request) => request.isSubscription,
      WebSocketLink(
        subscriptionQlHost,
        config: SocketClientConfig(
          initialPayload: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}, // Include token for WebSocketLink
        ),
      ),
      authLink.concat(httpLink),
    );

    client = GraphQLClient(
      link: link,
      cache: GraphQLCache(),
      defaultPolicies: DefaultPolicies(
        watchMutation: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
        watchQuery: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
        query: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
        mutate: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
        subscribe: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I listen for changes:

```
getIt<GraphQlClient>()
        .client
        ?.subscribe$OrderUpdated(
          Options$Subscription$OrderUpdated(
            fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.networkOnly,
            variables:
                Variables$Subscription$OrderUpdated(id: getIt<TabletChooserCubit>().state.selectedTablet?.id ?? ''),
          ),
        )
        .listen(_updateOrders);
```

And subscription doesnt work but all queries and mutations works fine, what can be a problem?
I get only this in log:

```
I/flutter (12107): Connected to websocket.
I/flutter (12107): Initialising connection
I/flutter (12107): Disconnected from websocket.
```

And this is what I get as first event on subscription:
[image]